# Jquery update table cell in loop function

Tags: jquery, html, json, loops, html-table

I need to update only my user-name field. Can anyone help me how to update that user-name value in jQuery?

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
   tr = $('<tr id="row'+i+'"/>');                                                         
   // tr.append("<td class='id_row' data-id_value='"+i+"'>" + response[i].id + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td class='name'>" + response[i].name + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td id='value"+i+"'>" + response[i].username + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td>" + response[i].email + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td>" + response[i].phone + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td>" + response[i].website + "</td>");    
   tr.append("<td>"+ '<button class="btn btn-danger update" data-check="'+i+'"> Update </button>'+ "</td>")   
   tr.append("<td>"+ elem + "</td>")          
   $('table').append(tr);
   }        
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get index of the iterating loop then try like this

```
$('#value'+i).val('updatedUsernameValue');
```

Or

```
$('tr:eq(2)').children().next().val('somevalue');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#value' + i).text('newUserName');` i should be any of the indexes.